# Issue on Removing Markers From Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can you please take a look at [this Link](http://iomhumanitarian.atwebpages.com/map.html) and let me know why I am not able to remove the Markers from the Map? I am getting this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'setMap'

Code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
$( "#trg" ).click(function() {
 $.ajax({
    // type: "POST",
    url: 'SO_20131215_data.json.txt',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data){ 
      locations.length = 0;
      for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
        locations.push(Array(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude));
        // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude),
          map: map,
          title:"marker "+p
        });
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr,status,errorStr) {
      alert("status="+status+", error="+errorStr);
    }

  }); 

});
  function removeMarkers() {
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                locations[i].setMap(null)
            }
        }

  $('#remover').click(function () {
            removeMarkers();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function removeMarkers() {
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            if(locations[i])
                 locations[i].setMap(null)
        }
    }
```

AND one more thing, inside the ajax success function :

```
   for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {

      //locations.push(Array(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude));

      // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude),
      map: map,
      title:"marker "+p
    });

    locations.push(marker);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On debugging you code, it seems *you're referring the locations (lat/lon) of the maps* like

```
locations[i].setMap(null)  //WRONG
```

Which is wrong.  The correct way to use **`setMap`** *is with Google maps's marker* like

```
function removeMarkers() {
            for (i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
                marker[i].setMap(null);  //refer marker
                marker[i] = null;  //if you wish to delete the marker
            }
        }
```

**FYI:**  In your code, `marker` variable is locally scope so try to change it as globally scoped.

Comment: Thanks Praveen but now I am getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined

Comment: Can you please let me know How I can access to locally scoped variable?

Comment: @Behseini just remove var from `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude),
          map: map,
          title:"marker "+p
        });`  or declare `var marker;` next to `map` variable so it is globally accessible

Comment: @Behseini sorry try like `var markers = [];` in globally then push each marker to this array like `markers.push(marker);` after marker.  hoe you can understand.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I tried but didnt work but Asif solution work. thanks alot for ur comments

Comment: @Behseini Actually I don't see any difference from my answer,  anyway you solved :)